# Dynamically created buttons

Tags: vb.net, button, boolean, action, dynamically-generated

Beginner level question
I have managed to dynamically add buttons to a form with values from an XML, as I do not knwo how many buttons or what button names will be used I am hitting the following roadblock

I can generate the buttons with each his own commond behind it but when i try to do a different action on first and second click (even or uneven) or (clicked or not clicked) the values transfer to the other buttons

Click the first button once, it performs the first action, then go to the second button, the second button thinks you already clicked it and performs the second action instead of the first action

on load i read the xml and create the buttons

```
Public Sub Button_Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Read XML into Dataset

        Try
            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(XML_file, New XmlReaderSettings())
            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)

            xmlFile.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            WriteErrors(ex)
        End Try



        'Create buttons to add to the aray of buttons before adding them to the form in Private Sub create_button()
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

            ButtonNumber = (ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0))
            NaamX = (ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1)).ToString
            CommandX = (ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2)).ToString

            'Create buttons
            Dim new_Button As New Button
            new_Button.Text = NaamX
            new_Button.Name = CommandX
            new_Button.Location = New Point(Location_control.X + 10,
                                            Location_control.Y)
            new_Button.Width = 155
            Location_control.Y += new_Button.Height + 10


            'Add an action to the button
            AddHandler new_Button.Click, AddressOf myButtonHandler_Click

            'Add button to list of buttons
            ButtonCount = ButtonCount + 1
            ListOfButtons.Add(new_Button)
            
        Next



        'After creating all buttons and adding to the list of buttons, create them on the form
        create_button()

        'Set Form size according to ButtonCount
        Dim formSize As Integer = (ButtonCount * 33) + 100
        Me.Size = New Size(187, formSize)
        Me.TopMost = True
        Me.Refresh()


    End Sub
```

Then I add an action to it, but the clicked values transfers over to all buttons

```
    'Add actions to the buttons
    Public Sub myButtonHandler_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        'Check if the map file exists,if not do not exit app 
        MapFile = sender.name

        'Get file details to check the extension
        FileDetail = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(MapFile)

        Dim FoundFlag As Integer = 0

        Look4File(MapFile, False, FoundFlag)

        'If map file is not found do nothing on button click
        If Not FoundFlag = 1 Then

            'Check if the extension is MAP
            If FileDetail.Extension = ".map" Then





                'If map file is found
                'Add to a list of maps used to detach all

                Dim clicked As Boolean

                If clicked = False Then

                    Maps2Detach.Add(MapFile)

                    'Gather the information to send to ExecuteTheCommand (exe, arguments, button used)
                    StartArgument = " ATTACH REFERENCE FILE -F " & " " & Chr(34) & MapFile & Chr(34)
                    ButtonNaam = sender.text

                    ExecuteTheCommand(CadCommandFile, StartArgument, ButtonNaam)

                    clicked = True
                Else

                    Maps2Detach.Remove(MapFile)

                    'Gather the information to send to ExecuteTheCommand (exe, arguments, button used)
                    StartArgument = " detach reference file -N " & " " & Chr(34) & MapFile & Chr(34)
                    ButtonNaam = sender.text

                    ExecuteTheCommand(CadCommandFile, StartArgument, ButtonNaam)

                    clicked = False

                End If

            Else

                ErrorMessage = "Not a MAP file: " & MapFile

                'Write to log
                Log_EveryThing(ErrorMessage)

                'Show msgbox
                MessageBox.Show(ErrorMessage, "Not a MAP file")


            End If


        Else

        End If

    End Sub
```

i am bit stuck trying to differ the click on buttons

Comment: The `sender` in the event handler is the `Button` that was clicked. Anything you need to do to that `Button` or store against that `Button` should be using that and only that.

Comment: If you want to do something different on every second click then you should probably use a `CheckBox` rather than a `Button`. You can set the `Appearance` to `Button` and it will look like a regular `Button` but it will depress and release on alternate clicks. You can then use the `Checked` property to determine what to do rather than counting clicks.

Comment: checkbox as button, will have a look at that sounds like an "easy" solution

Comment: If you do go with the `CheckBox`, you'd handle the `CheckedChanged` event rather than `Click` and then decide what to do based on the `Checked` property of the `sender`.

Comment: This is by far a lot easier, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!! works smooth now using the CheckBox pretending to be a button

Comment: Note that RadioButton controls have that same Appearance property, in case that comes in handy in the future.